# How does "return null!" resolve in a function?

Tags: typescript, null

Im looking through a project's code and one of their function's return statements reads

```
return null!;
```

What does "!" after null mean?
Also, when I rewrite it like:

```
return !null;
```

I get a linting error

Comment: That's _TypeScript_, and it's bonkers - they're returning `null` and asserting that it's [**not** `null`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-).

Comment: `return null!;` should be a syntax error (in JavaScript).

Comment: Ah, you're right I'll change the tag @Pointy